# Sleep 3 seconds before sending out next request using CURL

Tags: curl, sleep

I am parsing a website using the range function in CURL from terminal; note the 10 second sleep command before the next request is sent out.

However, I get this error message:

> Your access to this site has been
>   temporarily blocked. This blockwill be automatically
>   removed shortly, usually within a few minutes.The most frequent
>   cause for this blocking action is an automated response to
>   excessive webpage requests sent to the site from your IP address. If
>   you are using>                an automated downloading tool, please
>   slow the request rate down to less than one>                request
>   every 3 seconds.

This is the code(s) I am using:

```
while sleep 10; do curl "http://some.site.com/content[1-100]/[1-100]/[1-500].stuff"; done

while true; do curl "http://some.site.com/content[1-100]/[1-100]/[1-500].stuff"; sleep 10; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `[1-100]` syntax will repeat the request with numbers from 1..100 without returning, so your sleep is ignored.

I don't know a way to tell `curl` to throttle when you use the interval syntax, so I'd suggest you control this from outside `curl`, e.g.:

```
for a in {1..100}; do
    for b in {1..100}; do
        for c in {1..500}; do
            curl "http://some.site.com/content$a/$b/$c.stuff"
            sleep 3s
        done
    done
done
```